# Why do you need to reset javascript constructor during inheritance?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Why is it important that I reset the constructor from Mammal to Cat? I've been playing around with this code and haven't found any negative effects of having the "wrong" constructor.

```
function Mammal(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.offspring=[];
}

Cat.prototype = new Mammal();        // Here's where the inheritance occurs
Cat.prototype.constructor=Cat;       // Otherwise instances of Cat would have a constructor of Mammal

function Cat(name){
    this.name=name;
}
```

for example:

```
function Mammal(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.offspring=[];
}

Cat.prototype = new Mammal();        // Here's where the inheritance occurs


function Cat(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.hasFur = true;
}

c1 = new Cat();
alert(c1.hasFur); //returns true;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically you don't *need* to do that, but since you're replacing the entire `.prototype` object, you're losing the `.constructor` that's put there by default, so if you have code that relies on it, you need to manually include it.