# Get name of derived constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is it possible to get the name of the derived "class" in the following example?  I'd like to somehow have the output be "ChildClass", but instead it's "ParentClass".

```
function ParentClass() { this.name = 'Bob' }
function ChildClass() { this.name = 'Fred' }
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);

var child_instance = new ChildClass()
console.log('ChildClass type:', child_instance.constructor.name)
```

I realize I can do `this.my_type = 'ChildClass'` in the ChildClass constructor, but I have many classes that extend ParentClass and doing this everywhere would be inconvenient.

Comment: That's because your inheritance is not quite right.  http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: @SLaks The inheritance is alright. The problem is that OP has not reset the `constructor` property. Read the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093057/javascript-inheritance-and-the-constructor-property)

Comment: @AaditMShah: Exactly.  That's what I explain at the end of my blog post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you're overwriting the `prototype` property of `ChildClass` but you're not reseting the `constructor` property on the new prototype. You need to add one extra line:

```
function ParentClass() {
    this.name = "Bob";
}

function ChildClass() {
    this.name = "Fred";
}

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);

ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass; // add this line to your code
```

Now your code will work as expected. The following answer explains why your original code didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Personally I don't like writing "classes" like this with the constructor and the prototype dangling separately. It's just too tedious to type, incoherent, a pain on the eyes and difficult to maintain. Hence I use the following utility function to create classes:

```
function defclass(base, body) {
    var uber = base.prototype;
    var prototype = Object.create(uber);
    var constructor = (body.call(prototype, uber), prototype.constructor);
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

Now you can create classes as follows:

```
var ParentClass = defclass(Object, function () {
    this.constructor = function () {
        this.name = "Bob";
    };
});

var ChildClass = defclass(ParentClass, function () {
    this.constructor = function () {
        this.name = "Fred";
    };
});
```

This method has several advantages:

1. Inheritance and class definition have been combined into one.
2. The constructor is just another prototype method.
3. Everything is nicely encapsulated within a single closure.
4. Calling base class prototype methods is easy.
5. You can create private static functions easily.

Hope that helps.