# Typescript and the __proto__ attribute

Tags: typescript, prototype, chain

So every mention of __proto__ is usually followed by a reference to Brendan Eich's plea not to use it. I've been playing around with some reflection in Typescript, navigating the prototype chain of a class down to a provided ancestor class using it, and would love to inject a single prototype property holding class metadata.

Does anyone have any specifics on the performance overhead I might incur, or a solution that doesn't rely on __proto__?

EDIT - Updated with code. This is just a contrived example I typed out but it illustrates what I'm hoping to do. I'm not quite sure how to benchmark the percieved slowdown caused by __proto__ mutation. But I gave it a shot anyways. Instantiation, prototype property access and method calls execute no differently given the modification.

```
class Base {
    public getClassName() : string {
        return this['_className'] || undefined;
    }
}

class Intermediate extends Base {   
}

class Final extends Intermediate {  
}

function traverseProtoChain(derivedClass, baseClass) {
    var cursor = derivedClass.prototype;
    while (cursor instanceof baseClass) {
        if (isDefined(cursor.constructor)) {
            var className = getProtoName(cursor);
            if (isValidString(className)) 
                cursor['_className'] = getProtoName(cursor);
        }           

        if (isDefined(cursor.__proto__)) {
            cursor = cursor.__proto__;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: show the code which you have thought

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the ECMAScript 5.1 standard:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(cursor)
```

For really quite old versions of browsers, you could attempt to fall back to `__proto__` if `Object.getPrototypeOf` doesn't exist, but you can decide if those browsers are important given your specific context.

Here is an example that shows this. `bar.prototype` doesn't work, because it is an instance. `getPrototypeOf` works and gives you the same answer as the discouraged `__proto__`.

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name: string) {

    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

var bar = new Bar('x');

console.log(bar.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar));
console.log(bar.__proto__);
```

So you could write the "pleases everyone"...

```
if (Object.getPrototypeOf) {
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar));
} else if (bar.__proto__) {
    console.log(bar.__proto__);
}
```

Final curve-ball... `__proto__` is likely to become standardised in ECMAScript 6... worth bearing in mind!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. I was aware of of the get|setPrototypeOf, and have implemented a polyfill in my library. I was just looking for information about how it affects performance. Brendan Eich stated that given modern JS implementations, __proto__ mutation could negatively impact on performance.

Comment: The answer is always to measure it and see if it really does.